# Spark can read from phoenix but writing gives No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix error

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hbase

Recently, my Phoenix integration with Spark has been acting up. It was working very well until last week, as a matter of fact, there are still pieces of code running on the cluster using similar code. Only new code that I write does not seem to work properly and is giving weird errors while writing a data-frame to Phoenix -- reading works fine:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {
        if (args.length < 1) {
                    println("Needs a month range as: startingmonth,endingmonth")
                    System.exit(1)
            }

        val month_range = args(0).split(",")
        val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

        val start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("userProfile")//.set("spark.testing.memory", "536870912")


    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    /*val itemProfileDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
            .options(ImmutableMap.of("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver", "url",
                    "jdbc:phoenix:<ZK URL>:5181", "dbtable", "ITEMPROFILES")).load()
                    itemProfileDF.show() //[[ [ TAKE NOTE OF THIS COMMENTED PART] ]]*/

        val callUsageSummary = sqlContext.read.parquet("/edw_data_vol/hp_tab/CALL_USAGE_SUMMARY21_FCT")

     callUsageSummary.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(ImmutableMap.of("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver","zkUrl","jdbc:phoenix:<ZK URL>:5181","table","AGGREGATIONFINAL")).save()
 print("Done")
  var stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken to process the files" + (stop - start) / 1000 + "s")
    }
```

this code throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 70 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 70.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 13): java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:<ZK URL>:5181:/hbase;
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:82)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:70)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getUpsertColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:230)
at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:45)
at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

whereas If I uncomment the part which marked so you can notice, the code works just fine, but only in this particular classes, in other classes it's pretty much unreliable when it may or may not work. Mostly I can't figure out changing what where is going to make it work. It most probably isn't a problem with Phoenix as I have only noticed the result change after I repackage it with maven. Also, my older project runs just fine.

There are also classes in which the code was working just fine but now it does not after I repackaged them (I think).

in the command line I pass:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/lib/phoenix-spark-4.8.1-HBase-1.1.jar,/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.1-mapr-1602.jar"
```

I know neither of these is the client jar mentioned in the official Phoenix documentation. BUT THE CODE USED TO WORK WITH THESE, SOMETIMES IT STILL DOES. I have tried the client jars and every possible combination of these 3 jars for executors and driver. I have finally given up and writing here in case someone knows what might have happened.

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: I changed it. Thanks for pointing out.